# Random high CPU usage in ArangoDB large database

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bigdata, arangodb

I have a very large database (~ 50 million entries) built with latest ArangoDB Community Edition 3.7.8 and running in a proper (maybe even over) sized AWS EC2 instance. Most of the time memory usage is around 50% and CPU usage is average 20%.

The AWS EC2 instance is a:

```
c5.9xlarge
x86_64
vCPUs: 36
Memory: 72GB
```

Sometimes (once per day in random times) my backend java system stops accepting API requests and when I go to check the instance's CPU usage it's stuck 99% (used by arangodb, the java application remains with low CPU usage)

Now for example it's running fine

```
top - 19:31:50 up 23:49,  1 user,  load average: 9.50, 10.72, 12.74
Tasks: 341 total,   1 running, 340 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 20.3 us,  0.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 79.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem : 48.0/70240.8  [||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||                                     ]
MiB Swap:  0.0/0.0      [                                                                                     ]

PID   USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
907   arangodb  20   0  103.5g  23.3g  43900 S  19.1  34.0  23096:40 arangod
36171 root      20   0   42.9g   7.3g  29908 S   0.7  10.7 360:44.63 java
```

When the problem starts it will be something like this (99.9% CPU usage)

```
PID   USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
907   arangodb  20   0  103.5g  23.3g  43900 S  99.9  34.0  23096:40 arangod
36171 root      20   0   42.9g   7.3g  29908 S   0.7  10.7 360:44.63 java
```

I though it could be some problematic query that was being executed, but when the problem last occurred I checked the running and slow queries tabs and there was nothing wrong there... just fast queries being executed as always that takes up to 1 sec maximum. Some of them were a little slower, taking up to 3 secs, but that's all.

The database engine seemed locked doing something else.

My question is, how do I properly debug the database/engine to find out what's wrong?

Is there a command in **arangosh** to see which threads are being executed causing the system overload?

```
top - 16:04:29 up  8:30,  1 user,  load average: 35.50, 29.85, 26.79
Threads: 5874 total,  39 running, 5835 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 87.0 us, 12.4 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem : 44.1/70240.8  [||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||                                                        ]
MiB Swap:  0.0/0.0      [                                                                                                    ]

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
  34812 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.8  31.5   4:11.29 SchedWorker
  34815 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.8  31.5   4:00.48 SchedWorker
  34816 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.8  31.5   3:56.96 SchedWorker
  34796 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   4:29.74 SchedWorker
  34801 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   4:26.99 SchedWorker
  34804 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   4:22.92 SchedWorker
  34806 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   4:19.99 SchedWorker
  34810 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   4:14.07 SchedWorker
  34813 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   4:03.91 SchedWorker
  34817 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   3:48.18 SchedWorker
  34825 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   3:22.19 SchedWorker
  34830 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   3:13.76 SchedWorker
  34833 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   3:12.04 SchedWorker
  35107 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   1:11.55 SchedWorker
  34795 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   5:13.87 SchedWorker
  34803 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   3:42.99 SchedWorker
  34807 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   4:18.45 SchedWorker
  34814 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   4:03.00 SchedWorker
  34822 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   3:33.07 SchedWorker
  34823 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   3:30.12 SchedWorker
  34824 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   3:27.81 SchedWorker
  34971 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   2:27.33 SchedWorker
  34973 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   2:55.89 SchedWorker
  34802 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   4:24.70 SchedWorker
  34811 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   3:38.33 SchedWorker
  34820 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   3:41.70 SchedWorker
  34831 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   3:10.63 SchedWorker
  34808 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   4:16.61 SchedWorker
  34809 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   4:15.71 SchedWorker
  34829 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   3:14.97 SchedWorker
  35097 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   0:52.38 SchedWorker
  35118 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.7  31.5   1:05.96 SchedWorker
  34832 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.6  31.5   3:13.72 SchedWorker
  34821 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.6  31.5   3:37.70 SchedWorker
  34972 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.6  31.5   2:54.47 SchedWorker
  34805 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   2.5  31.5   4:20.85 SchedWorker
  35563 ubuntu    20   0   17712  10552   3196 R   0.3   0.0   0:00.74 top
    904 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 S   0.1  31.5   1:36.13 jemalloc_bg_thd
    997 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 S   0.1  31.5   2:00.13 jemalloc_bg_thd
   1001 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 R   0.1  31.5   2:01.31 jemalloc_bg_thd
  35572 root      20   0   43.1g   6.5g  29660 S   0.1   9.5   0:00.09 C2 CompilerThre
   1923 root      20   0   43.1g   6.5g  29660 S   0.0   9.5   0:29.03 https-jsse-nio-
   1012 arangodb  20   0   68.2g  21.6g  38104 S   0.0  31.5   1:46.39 jemalloc_bg_thd
     11 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:46.16 rcu_sched
   1330 root      20   0   43.1g   6.5g  29660 S   0.0   9.5   2:48.66 GC Thread#22
   1593 root      20   0   43.1g   6.5g  29660 S   0.0   9.5   0:28.92 https-jsse-nio-
   1598 root      20   0   43.1g   6.5g  29660 S   0.0   9.5   0:41.58 https-jsse-nio-
   1832 root      20   0   43.1g   6.5g  29660 S   0.0   9.5   0:28.95 https-jsse-nio-
   1905 root      20   0   43.1g   6.5g  29660 S   0.0   9.5   0:28.07 https-jsse-nio-
   2018 root      20   0   43.1g   6.5g  29660 S   0.0   9.5   0:28.44 https-jsse-nio-
   2021 root      20   0   43.1g   6.5g  29660 S   0.0   9.5   0:28.19 https-jsse-nio-
   2026 root      20   0   43.1g   6.5g  29660 S   0.0   9.5   0:28.55 https-jsse-nio-
   2064 root      20   0   43.1g   6.5g  29660 S   0.0   9.5   0:28.83 https-jsse-nio-
   2082 root      20   0   43.1g   6.5g  29660 S   0.0   9.5   0:28.11 https-jsse-nio-
   2086 root      20   0   43.1g   6.5g  29660 S   0.0   9.5   0:28.25 https-jsse-nio-
   2117 root      20   0   43.1g   6.5g  29660 S   0.0   9.5   0:28.52 https-jsse-nio-
   4900 root      20   0   43.1g   6.5g  29660 R   0.0   9.5   0:28.00 https-jsse-nio-
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can use `H` to make top show you the threads that are currently active. ArangoDB names them accordingly

Comment: you can use `H` to make top show you the threads that are currently active. ArangoDB names them accordingly. You could also use `--rocksdb.debug-logging true` to show a bit more about the database backend; the activity could be the compaction. Please note that running out of AWS "burst credits" can be an issue.

Comment: @dothebart **c5** instances does not have burst capabilities. Only the T2, T3, T3a, and T4g instances have this. I think my instance size is more than enough, because the average load is ~15% only. Now I tried disabling statistics and set log level to debug. Here's a message i found on the logs when the problem happened again a few hours ago: `2021-03-04T23:24:29Z [862] INFO [5b708] {engines} last RocksDB WAL sync happened longer ago than configured threshold. last sync happened 15662 ms ago, threshold value: 5000 ms`

Comment: @dothebart as you can see in the "top" output, seems the problem occurs when all 36 threads of the cpu are used by arangod, probably leaving nothing else for the java process. Maybe that's the reason the java backend API server stops responding.

Comment: Scheduler threads are actual worker threads. So you're seeing the wal compaction happening, and for that time the throughput of the db seems to be limited, and not to be able to sustain your load pattern.

Comment: It does not make any sense the way this "wal compaction" works. I can run my system fine with a 16x vCPU virtual machine. But when this "wal" thing starts cpu load will go from 15% to 99% hanging all my system. So i have to oversize and spend the double just to buy a 32x vCPU machine because of this. Is there a way to fix this so i don't have to waste money?

Comment: Did you change any rocksdb options? You can configure WAL size,  number of buffers, background threads, high priority threads etc.
https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/programs-arangod-rocksdb.html